# Combine two MutableStateFlows and emit values together?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

So, I've read a number of questions here, as well as blog posts, and documentation about the kotlin flow `combine` function. [The official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/combine.html) indicate that upon each emission from one of the flows, the *previous* value from the other flow(s) will also be emitted. I played around with this with [marbles](https://rxmarbles.com/#combineLatest) too to validate my expectations from older school ReactiveX approaches.

However, when I combine two flows, I see different behavior. When each flow emits, the values from the other flow(s) are empty / initial.

```
val itemFlow: MutableStateFlow<List<String>> = MutableStateFlow(listOf())
val cacheFlow: MutableStateFlow<Map<String, String>> = MutableStateFlow(mapOf())

combine(itemFlow, cacheFlow) { items, cache ->
    println("items: $items, cache: $cache")

    // transform the items + cache into a List<String> and return it to be collected...
}.collect {
    // operation on cache-updated list
}
```

Whenever I call `itemFlow.update { ... }`, I can see in my log statements that inside of `combine`'s transform block, it will print something like

```
items: (item1 item2 item3 item4), cache: []
```

Conversely, when I call `cacheFlow.update { ... }`, the opposite happens:

```
items: [], cache: (a : item1, b: item2)
```

I know I could probably just access the flow's `value` or something inside the block, but I'd rather just have it work as documented. I assume I'm missing something important as to how the operator works, or maybe it's a problem with using a `StateFlow` rather than some other implementation? I'm open to changing it, just looking for any help in getting my expected result, which would look like:

```
items: (item1, item2, item3, item4), cache: (a: item1, b: item2)
```

Comment: Is your expectation that the very first item emitted to this transform block will only occur after both flows have non-empty data?

Comment: Based on your code, it seems to be working as expected. Both flows are initialized to empty collections, so when you first update one, the other will still be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A StateFlow always has a current `value` that is the first thing immediately emitted to new collectors. That is why you **have** to provide an initial value to the `MutableStateFlow()` "constructor" or to the `stateIn` function.

So the `combine` function is operating according to its documentation that states that it combines "the most recently emitted values by each flow". The operator, under the hood, begins collecting the two flows when it gets collected. So the first item emitted by each of your StateFlows is its current/initial value of an empty collection.

When this combined flow is first collected, assuming it starts getting collected before you start updating the source flows, it will necessarily first see a transform where the incoming values are two empty collections. Then, when you update one of the two source StateFlows, it will see the new data from that source flow combined with the most recent `value` from the other source flow, which is still an empty collection.

If your goal is for the first thing in the combined flow to be non-initial empty collections from each of the two sources, you might want to use SharedFlows instead of StateFlows, so they don't have to have some initial value. You can still give them `replay = 1` so that new collectors will still receive the most recent data if it already exists.

The downside is there is no `update` function for SharedFlow, since there is no notion of a *current value* for a SharedFlow. It may or may not have some values in its buffer. If your new value doesn't have to depend on what the value of the previous value is, then you don't need `update` anyway and can use `emit` on it instead.

If SharedFlow isn't suitable, I think you will have to do some sort of filtering on your combined flow, which may be very convoluted if it's possible that you sometimes have valid data that is an empty collection.

Maybe something like this?

```
private val initialEmptyList: List<String> = ArrayList() // don't use listOf() or emptyList() because these return a global instance
private val initialEmptyMap: Map<String, String> = HashMap() // same

val itemFlow: MutableStateFlow<List<String>> = MutableStateFlow(initialEmptyList)
val cacheFlow: MutableStateFlow<Map<String, String>> = MutableStateFlow(initialEmptyMap)

combine(
    itemFlow.filter { it !== initialEmptyList }, // note, reference equality check
    cacheFlow.filter { it !== initialEmptyMap }  // same
) { items, cache ->
    //...
```